# Don't rat out the secret answer

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Here's a riddle for the day

> One fell in love with his music system
>   Another led the opposers in Queensland
>   One played the man playing a trick
>   The last lost his love by his own hand

Hint 1:

> Queensland is not the Australian state here. Read it aloud.

Hint 2:

> Hunter's answer is certainly on the right track.

Hint 3:

> The title is also a clue.

Hint 4: (big one)

> Queensland isn't one word.

__Hint 5: (AND THE BIGGEST ONE YET)

> [In his question, Engineer Toast has been inspired a lot more than he thinks.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16878/whats-our-name-also-improve-my-riddle?lq=1) (Or maybe he knows, but I'm not sure.)

Comment: Well, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queensland_%28disambiguation%29) was no help at all...

Comment: @EngineerToast: Read it out loud. Maybe I took it a bit too far in trying to be obscure.

Comment: I'm guessing your hint about "Queensland" means you're talking about Alice from *Through the Looking Glass*, who commanded the black army against the Queen of Hearts' red army.

Comment: @JoeZ. not quite. But I like the way you think. Think more about what it sounds like.

Comment: @EngineerToast: Now that my riddle is solved, did you know that the answer to mine was the same as yours? (You were a bit more verbose and used a lot more characters in your riddle.)

Comment: @CodeNewbie No! I had no idea! That's freaking' amazing. It makes sense, though. It turns out I deciphered the Queensland clue correctly but, when I couldn't find the rest, I figured I had it wrong. That was the launching pad for my own riddle, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to try this one, even if I'm not convinced:

> Edward

I don't have great explanations, though:

One fell in love with his music system

> <strike>Edward Williams created the Soundbeam music system.</strike> Based on the other hint in the comments, this is actually Edward Maya, because of his song called "Stereo Love" (definitely not my genre, I would have never found it out).

Another led the opposers in Queensland

> <strike>Edward Hand, maybe? He's been a general in the Continental Army during the Revolutionary War. I thought of Edward Braddock first, but I find it hard to say he "led the opposers".</strike> Ed Milliband comes to mind, he was leader of the opposition from 2010 to 2015.

One played the man playing a trick

> Well, Edward Norton in The Illusionist.

The last lost his love by his own hand

> This made me think of Edward Scissorhands, even if he didn't exactly "lost his love by his hand".

And about the question title:

> <strike>apparently at least two rodent species are named like that: Edward's swamp rat and Edwards's long-tailed giant rat.</strike> Probably Edward Snowden, who leaked information from the NSA.

Comment: Edward is correct! First Edward is not an inventor or scientist, but an EDM artist known for his song '*** Love'. *** is where the music system part fits in.

Comment: Oh, ok, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Also, Edward who led the opposers in "Queen's land" is different. I'm talking about a politician. And for the title, I'm talking about a famous Edward who was a rat (not the animal). (Also, what he did was rat out the _secret_).

Comment: Edited again, I hope I got it right this time. Otherwise I fear it's going to be a long trial-and-error session :)

Comment: Perfect now! :)

Answer (score 7):

This is my guess... The answer could be:

> (the surname) NEWMAN

```
One fell in love with his music system
```

> Alfred Newman: developed what came to be known as the Newman System, a means of synchronising the performance and recording of a musical score with the film.

```
Another led the opposers in Queensland
```

> <s>Campbell Newman was elected to lead the LNP into the 2012 Queensland state election</s>
> (Being *Queensland* actually *Queen's Land*) John Henry Newman, who became known as a leader of, and an able polemicist for, the Oxford Movement, an influential and controversial grouping of Anglicans who wished to return to the Church of England many Catholic beliefs and liturgical rituals from before the English Reformation.

```
One played the man playing a trick
```

> Paul Newman, who played a pool player in "The color of money" and in "The hustler".

```
The last lost his love by his own hand
```

> The singer John Newman (is it a reference to "Out Of My Head" lyrics? )

Comment: Anyway, I suppose that the solution is a surname... ;)

Comment: I'm still stuck to my first guess... I changed one of the answers, due to the hint about Queensland...

Comment: I assure you, it isn't Newman. With Newman, your second and third clue fit very well indeed, but the first and fourth are rather loosely fit. Again, check the question linked in hint 5 (where I had previously wrongly mentioned your name instead of EngineerToast).

Comment: Also, you haven't found the link with the question title.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe they're

> bridge players.

*One fell in love with his music system*

> Not sure about this line.

*Another led the opposers in Queensland*

> This player is opposite another and has lots of queens in his hand.

*One played the man playing a trick*

> A round of play in bridge is called a trick, so at any time each player is playing another who's playing a trick.

*The last lost his love by his own hand*

> This player's hand was so bad that he lost the game, and with it whatever he'd wagered (he probably loves money).

Comment: Interestng answer, rand. But nothing related.

Answer (score 1):

My guess:

> Henry

One fell in love with his music system

> Henry Kloss developed the first portable music system.

Another led the opposers in Queensland

> Patrick Henry against the British Army (Queen's Land)

One played the man playing a trick

> This one, I cannot figure out. Best I've got is King Henry IV (the play).

The last lost his love by his own hand

> King Henry V killed his own wives.

Comment: And yes, I can confirm that you've got the correct interpretation of Queensland. :)