# What's our Name? (Also: improve my riddle)

Tags: riddle, puzzle-creation, knowledge

I've thrown together a quick riddle inspired by the as-of-yet unsolved riddle from [CodeNewbie](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/16838/9000). I don't feel like it's very solid, though, and the cadence isn't quite right. It's easy to show that the right answer fits everything but I'm worried about two things:

1. Arriving at that right answer may not be an easily deduced answer. I like things you can *solve* instead of things that require an epiphany.
2. There could be an answer I haven't thought of that fits better

Can you 1) Answer the riddle and / or 2) Once the answer is known, think of some suggestion for where it needs tightening up?

(Edited based on suggestions)

> We protect wealth and have wealth ourselves
>   My brothers do, and I
>   We share the name, the same name all
>   I swear I do not lie
>
> One is thoughtful, simple, kind
>   But rather slow at best
>   To ponder he must think, think, think
>   Under Sanders he will rest
>   He has a hard time hearing
>   When ears get all stuffed up
>   He was renamed at 1 year old
>   Causing some mixup
>
> One told secrets and angered some
>   He's fled now far away
>   Called a traitor; booed and hissed
>   It's best to stay away
>   Others think he is a hero
>   And wonder how he fares
>   His surname was in Heller's book
>   Confuses polar bears
>
> One tried to save his mother but
>   He failed quite miserably
>   It cost him an arm and leg
>   To fail so blatantly
>   This brother's brother is not my brother
>   Though he paid his own high price
>   He lost his body - saved his soul
>   Two brothers' sacrifice
>
> Many brothers have been kings for sure
>   Thus far there are one through eight
>   There will sure one day be more
>   Of our royal ruling mates
>
> One was only one of us
>   When he was not himself
>   His formula of wondrous hide
>   Should go back on the shelf
>
> One loved riddles, puzzles, jokes
>   Mentally deranged bloke
>   He wears green and laughs too much
>   Not proud of *all* kinfolk...
>
> Train, vampire, and bladed hands
>   A platypus (to kids from oughts)
>   We are many myriad
>   Our name is what is sought

Comment: I think I saw FMA in somewhere! (using short form to avoid spoiler)

Comment: In England (UK) there have actually been eight. Though, in fairness, the eighth didn't live up to the title, so to speak. Still enough for the next one to be the ninth.

Comment: @Carmi I wasn't sure to include the king of less than a year. I probably should, though, right? He *was* King Edward for a time.

Comment: I actually thought that "One was only one of us 
When he was not himself" referred to him, as he was normally known as Albert (Bertie). He is officially counted as a king, so yes.

Comment: @Alex FMA is actually where I started and expanded out from there.

Comment: Now that CodeNewbie's riddle has been solved, I'm almost tempted to close this as a duplicate! :-o ;-)

Comment: @randal'thor I truly had no idea. I solved the Queensland clue but, when I couldn't get the rest, I figured I was wrong. That was the launching board for my own riddle.

Comment: There have actually been eleven King Edwards of England.  Edward the Elder, Edward the Martyr, Edward the Confessor (Saxon kings), and then Edward I through VIII.  And Edward VIII is definitely counted as one of the kings of England, even though he was king for less than a year.  Though if you're going to go down that path, you might discount Edward V (one of the princes in the tower) as well, since he was never crowned.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is their name

> Edward

We protect wealth and have wealth ourselves  
My brothers do, and I  
We share the name, the same name all  
I swear I do not lie

> This is explaining the riddle, in addition to Edward meaning "Wealthy Guard"

One is thoughtful, simple, kind  
But rather slow at best  
To ponder he must think, think, think  
Under Sanders he will rest  
He has a hard time hearing  
When ears get all stuffed up  
He was renamed at 1 year old  
Causing some mixup

> Thanks to Engineer Toast's extra clues I now know this is Winnie the Pooh, originally his name was Edward Bear

One told secrets and angered some  
He's fled now far away  
Called a traitor; booed and hissed  
It's best to stay away  
Others think he is a hero  
And wonder how he fares  
His surname was in Heller's book  
Confuses polar bears

> Edward Snowden I believe? Is Heller's book Catch-22?

One tried to save his mother but  
He failed quite miserably  
It cost him an arm and leg  
To fail so blatantly  
This brother's brother is not my brother  
Though he paid his own high price  
He lost his body - saved his soul  
Two brothers' sacrifice

> Edward Elric - from Full Metal Alchemist

Many brothers have been kings for sure  
Thus far there are one through seven  
There will sure one day be more  
Of our royal ruling brethren

> This is referencing the British royal Family, Edward the 7th is the most recent King Edward

One was only one of us  
When he was not himself  
One loved riddles, puzzles, jokes  
Mentally deranged

> I didn't realize this was two clues thanks for the clarification. first one is Dr. Jekyl/Mr. Hyde, second: The Riddler a.k.a Edward Nygma

Train, vampire, "monster", too  
A platypus to kids from oughts  
We are many myriad  
Tell us, what's our name?

> Train: Edward From Thomas the tank engine, Vampire: Edward Cullen from Twilight, Monster: Edward Scissor Hands (This clue was a but of a stretch), Platypus: Edward from Camp Lazlo

Comment: I think you got it!  Better with full explanation on each line thou

Comment: I was adding it in after the fact, I'm really bad at SE formatting so I wanted to get the answer in first then add the explanation when I had time to format it

Comment: I think for the first stanza, it is also referencing Edward Jones, the investment company (or the guy who founded the Dow Jones).

Comment: You definitely got the name. I see a few points where I need to improve based on what you missed: 1) Edward means "wealthy guard" so the first stanza *is* actually a clue. 2) Stanza 2 talks about a tubby little cubby all stuffed with fluff whose original name is long forgotten by most. 3) Stanza 6 actually references two different Edwards although the first two lines do not clearly point to Edward Hyde. He and Riddler might need their own stanzas. 4) The "monster" was meant to be Edward Scissorhands but I forgot to flesh out the clues. ("Oughts" refers to the years 2000-'09 when the show ran.)

Comment: Updated, I thought it was good overall, I think the problem with the Riddler/Hyde Stanza is that both of them have alter egos so I assumed "When he was not himself " was a reference to the Riddler's actual name. And Honestly I wasnt even looking for a clue in stanza 1 so thats on me too.

Comment: The second one was obvious to me, so the rest might have been easier to deduce. It would have taken me a bunch of Googling (or reading [this page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/?title=Edward)).

Comment: @Tim Camp Lazo gets the whole line. There's no punctuation in there so I thought it'd be interpreted as such. Does it need to change? I've updated based on the suggestions so far.

Comment: @IanMacDonald You're on a mobile, aren't you? That list helped me expand the paltry few lines I started with.

Comment: @EngineerToast Maybe "A platypus (to kids from oughts)"

Comment: @Tim Ding done.

Answer (score 4):

Here are my suggestions for tightening up the cadence and flow:

> We shelter wealth and own it too
> My brethren and I
> We share a name, the same name all
> I swear I do not lie
>
> One is thoughtful, simple, kind
> But rather slow at best
> To ponder he must think, think, think
> 'Neath Sanders he will rest
> He has a hard time hearing
> When his ears get all stuffed up
> His name was changed at 1 year old
> Which muddled some things up
>
> By telling secrets, one drew ire
> He's fled now far away
> Booed and hissed; a traitor named
> It's best to stay away
> To others, though, he's quite the star
> They wonder how he fares
> His surname, found in Heller's book,
> Confuses polar bears
>
> One tried to save his mother but
> He failed quite mis'rably
> It cost him both an arm and leg
> To fail so blatantly
> This brother's brother's not my kin
> Though he paid quite a price
> His body lost, but saved his soul
> Two brothers' sacrifice
>
> Many brothers have been kings
> To date we've one through eight
> There surely will one day be more
> Majestic ruling mates
>
> One was only one of us
> When he was not himself
> His brew to hide his ugly trait
> Should go back on the shelf
>
> One loves riddles, puzzles, jokes
> He's mentally deranged
> With verdant garb and jovial air
> He plays his threat'ning games
>
> A train, a vampire, hands with blades
> A platypus (to kids from oughts)
> We are sundry and diverse
> Our name is what is sought

Comment: This requires pronouncing "brethren" with three syllables (breth-er-en, which is not technically correct, but common), and "vampire" with two (which is technically correct, but it's often pronounced "vam-pie-er"), and "jovial" with two.

Comment: +1 Bravo on a mighty leap forward! It's much more riddle-y now.

Comment: *aughts, perhaps?